# Azure pipelines triggers multiple times for the same commit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, lerna, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using Azure YAML pipelines to build a lerna monorepo repository. The problem that given the fact it's a monorepo with multiple applications, sometimes I have a multiple tags on the same commit (because more then one artifact was released). Is it possible to trigger the pipeline only once?
Actual configuration looks like :

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  tags:
    include:
    - refs/tags/*
```

and if I push a commit on master with 2 tags, it will run my pipeline 3 times.. one for master branch match and 1 time per tag.

Is it possible to configure the pipeline to run only once in this case?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You may try [batch ci runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs)

> If you have many team members uploading changes often, you may want to reduce the number of runs you start. If you set batch to true, when a pipeline is running, the system waits until the run is completed, then starts another run with all changes that have not yet been built.

```yaml
# specific branch build with batching
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps pipeline yaml, a CI build is automatically triggered on a default branch. So you need to disable the automatic CI trigger in order to have the second pipeline ONLY run when the first completes.

At the top of your second pipeline file, add:

```
trigger: 
  - none
```

Which will disable the automatic CI build.

Microsoft's documentation refers to this problem, but it isn't very clear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#combining-trigger-types